# How to enable mod_userdir for specific user on cpanel?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-userdir

I know that in cPanel/WHM you can allow users to preview their site using `http://server_ip/~username`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these steps

1.From WHM: Main >> Security Center >> Apache mod_userdir Tweak

2.Tick Enable mod_userdir Protection

3.Untick every thing under column heading Exclude Protection

4.Locate the virtual host that you wish to use from the list under column heading Host.

5.Input the cPanel account username, or usernames as a space-separated list, under the column heading Additional Users.
6.Click Save, at the bottom of the page, to submit and finalize changes.